# How can I load in a pipe (|) delimited text file that has columns that sometimes contain line breaks?

Tags: vb.net, ssis, csv

I have built an SSIS package that loads in several delimited text files into a SQL database.  One of the files often contains line spaces in it, which breaks the standard data flow task of setting a flat file source and mapping to an ado.net destination since it thinks it is on a new line when it reaches a line break.  The vendor sending over the files does not want to sent the file without any edits and can't do XML at this time.  Is there any way to fix this?  I was thinking of writing a small vb.net program that would correct the files so they would work in the SSIS package, but not sure how to write that logic.  The file has 5 columns, the first 2 are big integer and always contain some long integer ID, then there is a small text column that just contains one short word, then a date, and then a long comments field that is causing the problem.  The comments field is sometimes blank (which is ok), the problem are the rows that have line breaks.  I never know how many line breaks are in the comments, some have none, some can have several, even multiple line breaks in a row, so was wondering if this is even possible.

5787626|6547599|Approved|1/10/2017|Applicant request for fee waiver approved
5443221|7742812|Active|11/5/2013|
3430962|7643957|Re-Scheduled|5/25/2016|REVISED TERMS AND CONDITIONS REJECTED
Applicant has 30 DAYS To submit paperwork for extension.
34433624|7673715|Denied|1/24/2017|
34113575|7653748|Active|1/8/2014|New terms have been granted.

Sample File Format.

[image: Sample File Format]

Comment: I've done something similar. Take a guideline from my approach. I created a staging table with 30 columns(my pipe separated columns were fixed to MAX 30). Now read the pipe seaparated columns and write them in txt file. Then again read from text and put them in staging table. Delete the txt file after writing. Hope this make sense ?

Comment: I don't understand, if I load the file into a staging table, then I am left with a staging table that has data in columns that do not make sense.  For example, that would leave me with text such as "Applicant has 30 days" in a column that should only contain a big integer value.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for ? I think I misunderstood your output requirement.

Comment: I want to be able load a flat-file delimited text into a SQL table.  The issue is that the last column in the flat-file has no ending delimiter, it uses the CRLF (line space) to indicate to go to the next line and often that last column has line spaces in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is logic that you can program/predict, it will be possible.

I would do it using a Script Component as a source, which means you don't need to rewrite the file before processing it. It also provides a lot of flexibility, e.g., you can store values in variables while iterating over multiple lines in the file, etc.

I posted another answer recently that gives a lot of detail on how to go about this: [SSIS import a Flat File to SQL with the first row as header and last row as a total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737537/ssis-import-a-flat-file-to-sql-with-the-first-row-as-header-and-last-row-as-a-to/46738195#46738195).

An example of holding the values in variables until the row is ready to be written:-

For this example I am writing three columns, ID1, ID2 and Comments. The file looks like this:

```
1|2|Comment1
Comment2
4|5|Comment3
Comment4
Comment5
6|7|Comment6
```

The Script Component contains the following method.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        bool readFirstLine = false;
        int id1 = 0;
        int id2 = 0;
        string comments = null;

        reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Variables.FilePath); // this refers to a package variable that contains the file path

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            if (line.Contains("|"))
            {
                if (readFirstLine)
                {
                    Output0Buffer.AddRow();

                    Output0Buffer.ID1 = id1;
                    Output0Buffer.ID2 = id2;
                    Output0Buffer.Comments = comments;
                }
                else
                {
                    readFirstLine = true;
                }

                string[] fields = line.Split('|');

                id1 = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
                id2 = Convert.ToInt32(fields[1]);
                comments = fields[2];
            }
            else
            {
                comments += " " + line;
            }

            if (reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();

                Output0Buffer.ID1 = id1;
                Output0Buffer.ID2 = id2;
                Output0Buffer.Comments = comments;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

The result set is:

```
ID1    ID2    Comments
===    ===    ========
1      2      Comment1 Comment2
4      5      Comment3 Comment4 Comment5
6      7      Comment6
```

Comment: I can't use a sub-string since the length of digits/characters in fields are not fixed length, and cannot even do a  split on the (|) character into an array since often that last comments field is blank and it reads in the first line of the next line in the comments field.

Comment: Could you do something in your logic whereby if a line contains no pipes you just add that string to the end of the comments field of the previous row? You could use variables for each field and only create a row once you know it is complete, i.e. you read a new line that contains pipes.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea, but not sure how to do that where you go back and append to the previous row.

Comment: I have added an example to my answer, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: No problem! Please remember to mark the answer as correct. Thanks :)