# SSIS Processing money fields with what looks like signs over the last digit

Tags: ssis

I have a fixed length flat file input file. The records look like this

40000003858172870114823        0010087192017092762756014202METFORMIN HCL ER 500 MG       0000001200000300900000093E00000009E00000000{0000001{00000104{JOHN      DOE    196907161423171289         2174558M2A2           000                     xxxx        YYYYY       100000000000       000020170915001 00010000300          000003zzzzzz         000{000000000{000000894{ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa              P2017092700000000{00000000{00000000{00000000{  0000000{00000{  F89863         682004R0900001011B2017101109656     500 MG      2017010100000000{88044828665760

If you look just before the JOHN DOE you will see a field that represents a money field. It looks like 00000104{.

This looks like the type of field I used to process from a mainframe many years ago. How do I handle this in SSIS. If the { on the end is in fact a 0, then I want the field to be a string that reads 0000010.40.

I have other money fields that are, e.g. 00000159E. If my memory serves me correctly, that would be 00000015.95.

I can't find anything on how to do this transform.

Thanks,

Dick Rosenberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. import the values as strings

00000159E
00000104{

2. in derived column do your transforms with replace:

replace(replace(col,"E","5"),"{","0")

3. in another derived column cast to money and divide by 100

(DT_CY)(drvCol) / 100

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to either use a Script Component source in the data flow, or use a Derived Column transformation or Script Component transformation. I'd recommend a Script Component either way as it sounds like your custom logic will be fairly complex.

I have written a few detailed answers about how to implement a Script component source:

[SSIS import a Flat File to SQL with the first row as header and last row as a total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737537/ssis-import-a-flat-file-to-sql-with-the-first-row-as-header-and-last-row-as-a-to/46738195#46738195)

[How can I load in a pipe (|) delimited text file that has columns that sometimes contain line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779816/how-can-i-load-in-a-pipe-delimited-text-file-that-has-columns-that-sometimes/46789289#46789289)

Essentially, you need to locate the string, "00000104{", for example, and then convert it into decimal/money form before adding it into the data flow (or during it if you're using a Derived Column Transformation).

This could also be done in a Script Component transformation, which would function in a similar way to the Derived Column transformation, only you'd perhaps have a bit more scope for complex logic. Also in a Script Component transformation (as opposed to a source), you'd already have all of your other fields in place from the Flat File Source.